# Contcatform7 or Ninja form data store in custom database table - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wampserver, contact-form, ninja-forms

I use both Ninja Form and Contact Form 7 to access user input. But the problem I face is that the submission get stored in default tables(wp_post and wp_metapost). I feel it inconvenient to access the entered submission. So I wanted to store the submission into my user defined table in the same db. How can I do that?

I'm using a wordpress site with Ninja form (contact form 7 is also fine), Mysql local wamp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check below steps how you can add data in custom database table.

1) Create database table using following query

```
CREATE TABLE contactfordata(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50)
 );
```

2) Create contact form 7 form with following field

```
[text* name] 
[submit "Send"]
```

3) Add following code in fucntions.php file

```
 remove_all_filters ('wpcf7_before_send_mail');
 add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'before_send_mail_contactform7' );  

 function before_send_mail_contactform7( $formdata_db ) 
{

   $mydb_CUSTOM = new wpdb('DB_USERNAME','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME','HOST_NAME'); // add db detail here

   $formdata_db = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

  if ( $formdata_db ) 
    $formData = $formdata_db->get_posted_data();

  $name = $formData['name']; // set form data in variable

   $mydb_CUSTOM->insert( 'contactfordata', array( 'name' =>$name ), array( '%s' ) ); // insert the data in your custom table.
}
```

This will work for you code is tested.

Comment: What is $formdata_db? What should I replace there? Is it the name of the form used?

Comment: What to do when inserting more than one field values?

Comment: just add the other fields in database and append in the array where name is inserting.